# Port number in window.open method

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

```
function book_now(elem)
{
var hotel_id=elem.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML;
var twelve=elem.parentNode.parentNode.children[4].innerHTML;
var twenty_four=elem.parentNode.parentNode.children[4].innerHTML;
window.open("http://localhost:8080/Voyage_Operator/hotelbooking.jsp?      hotel_id="+hotel_id+"&twelve="+twelve ,"_self");

}
```

This is my code for a function which passes two variables in the URL specified in `window.open` method. In my laptop the port number is `8080`, but when I run it in my friend's laptop it showed an error because on his laptop the port number was `8084`.

Since this url is static in nature so how can I make my program run on other pc and to change the port number according to the current system ?

Comment: that is becuase of localhost, if you tried in a normal server it should work

Comment: @jycr753  thanks. Hope it will work :|